Why was answer 5195 to "Is there a psychological basis for getting hiccups?" deleted?
Why has this answer to Is there a psychological basis for getting hiccups? been converted to a comment and deleted?
And how can it be improved to meet the policy and standards of this site? IIrc it was an accepted answer.

I'll let whomever covered it respond but I agree it should be a comment. It's too short and has no reference to be an answer.

Conversion to comment implies that the answer is deleted, since it should have been a comment in the first place.
In the answer you seemingly recognized yourself it was not a full answer:

You explicitly stated not having the necessary reference at hand.
You acknowledged it was an incomplete answer by stating "Why does lack of carbon dioxide cause that, I don't know."

Hence, it's possibly a useful comment, but it does not live up to the expected clarity of an answer here on CogSci.

You could've argued CO_2 isn't a psychological basis as well.
